# SmtpMail.Send() doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a problem with send mail in c#; it doesn't send any mail and also doesn't throw any exceptions with failure :

```
using System.Web.Util;

public static void SendEmail(string _FromEmail, string _ToEmail, string _Subject, string _EmailBody)
    {

        // setup email header . 
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
        MailMessage _MailMessage = new MailMessage();

        _MailMessage.From = _FromEmail;
        _MailMessage.To = _ToEmail;
        _MailMessage.Subject = _Subject;
        _MailMessage.Body = _EmailBody;

        try
        {
            SmtpMail.Send(_MailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new ApplicationException("error has occured: " + ex.Message); 
        }

    }
```

please help!

Comment: Is your local smtp server sending mail out successfully?

Comment: Do you have an smtp server running on your local machine?

Comment: Is your local SMTP server setup to send email? Does the smart host it is using accept email from it?

Comment: yes i have : IIS SMPT virtual Server

Comment: Are you sure it's not sending the mail?  Or is it sending it but the recipient just isn't receiving it?  A lot of mail hosts ignore mail from sketchy sources, and a random person's PC is considered a sketchy source.

Comment: Does the smart host it is using accept email from it?? what doesn you mean with smart host?>>what i did is that i add 127.0.0.1 in relay of SMPT server and also enable basic authentication.

Comment: yes i am sure that i sent it.also i sent it my self as you see in code snippet :: LogicLayer.SendEmail("ragaei.mahmoud@invensys.com", "ragaei.mahmoud@invensys.com", "hiii", "first email");

Comment: also i tried to change both of the sender and recipient to other mail accounts

Comment: You added 127.0.0.1 to your SMTP server?  You mean *your* box, or your company's SMTP server?

Comment: no my PC not company..i am using my local SMPT server

Answer (score 1):

Check the folders in your IIS' Mailroot directory (probably located in C:\InetPub\Mailroot). Chances are your mails are dropped there, probably in the Badmail or the Queue directory.

Comment: @ Roy : i check it : C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Queue.it full with mails such this (NTFS_6c2eb4dc01cc301d00000006.EML)

Comment: Then you must configure your IIS Smtp service to use a proper SMTP server, such as an Exchange server. The IIS Smtp service is just a relay. Anyway, you've found your answer :-)

Comment: I don't get this point "IIS Smtp service to use a proper SMTP server" :S :S :S :S

Comment: The IIS Smtp server is not a real server, it just relays your messages to another SMTP server. For it to do that, you must configure it to point to a working SMTP server, such as an Exchange server or a PostFix server. Otherwise, IIS Smtp just stores everything locally in those drop folders, and the messages never get sent.

Comment: so how to make my IIS Smpt refer or point to this another SMPT server.?

Comment: For IIS 6, see http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e4cf06f5-9a36-474b-ba78-3f287a2b88f2.mspx?mfr=true, and for IIS 7, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058(WS.10).aspx.

Comment: I am new member in this communty..from where can i accept the answer..I hope it is easy as Like in Facebook ;)

Comment: It's the little checkbox by each answer.  You click the checkbox of the answer you accept.

Answer (score 0):

see C:\InetPub\Mailroot\queue folder. if your emails got stuck in this folder then 
1>> stop your SMTP
2>> move emails from queue folder to C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup folder and start your smtp server and wait for few seconds.

if your email got stuck in queue folder again then you need to enable smtp logging for more information. use this link to see how to enable smtp logging.

http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Logging_the_SMTP_Service.html